# Why my query is slower if a date column is in the SELECT part of my query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a strange behavior with my mysql query below:

```
SELECT domain_id, domain_name, domain_lastupdate 
FROM   domains 
WHERE  domain_id > 300000 LIMIT 2000
```

takes ~ 15seconds...

while

```
SELECT domain_id, domain_name 
FROM   domains 
WHERE  domain_id > 300000 LIMIT 2000
```

takes ~ 0.05seconds...

I've tried different ids with different limits doing one before the other and the other way around not to get cached results, but I end up with dramatic time differences.

I have 1 index on the domain_id, 1 on the domain_name, but none with both columns...

I just don't get it...

#

The domain_lastupdate is a simple Date column.

Here's the EXPLAIN output of both queries:

```
explain SELECT domain_id, domain_name, domain_lastupdate FROM domains WHERE domain_id > 255000 LIMIT 500;
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | domains | range | UN_domainid   | UN_domainid | 4       | NULL | 12575357 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

second one:

```
explain SELECT domain_id, domain_name FROM domains WHERE domain_id > 255000 LIMIT 500;
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | domains | range | UN_domainid   | UN_domainid | 4       | NULL | 12575369 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+----------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Any idea why the first one doesn't use the index ?

Comment: Run an EXPLAIN on each query, to help see where the difference is.

Comment: Hum... The first one is not using an index while the second is..
  #########   
1 | SIMPLE      | domains | range | UN_domainid   | UN_domainid | 4       | NULL | 9251492 | Using where; Using index
   ##########   
any guess why  @Andrew ?

Comment: Confusingly, the abscence of using index doesn't  mean it didn't use an index to find the rows (that's what they key column does). It means that mysql was able to use the index as a covering index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are pulling out the non date columns that you have indexed the SQL Server is able to pull your data directly out of the index and needn't go to the table at all.  To get the date it is having to hit the table.  Add an index on the date column.

Also I suppose you could create a multi column index.  Make sure you have domain_id as the first column in the index. [Creating Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)

What you want to use is what is called [A Covering Index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/glossary.html#glos_covering_index)

Comment: VERY Interesting perception... I never thought of it that way, but completely makes sense...  But how so then via the issue of the domain_name.. it too was not part of the index and would have had to retrieve that anyhow right?

Comment: This is actually what I figured out in the end. The MySQL table is innoDB and my PRIMARY key is the domain_name, therefore the data is ordered by domain_name instead of domain_id, which is really bad... I am modifying the order at the moment. Thanks!

Comment: @DRapp The OP said there IS an index on domain_name just not multi-column. So it's acting as a covering index and pulling data strictly from the 2 indexes and not scanning the table. You can see this by the time it takes too, the OP is using InnoDB and likely a b-tree index and that's why the covering index query is so quick, even with 12M rows returned, vs the other one is doing a table scan and taking 300x as long.
It's helpful to think of these things in terms of their underlying datastructures, it helps you to be able to generalize your knowledge, for instance I've never even used MySQL :p